# Junção de colunas: HTML5 e Angular

Tags: angularjs, table

Galera, estou querendo saber como eu posso fazer essa junção com o angularjs? Vi que tem o ng-repeat-start e o end, mas não consegui implementar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Talvez isso te ajude (SO em inglês): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104750/use-of-rowspan-to-group-hierarchical-data#26834906

Comment: Você precisa colocar o JSON que está usando de modelo para montar as tabelas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O recurso de unir linhas no `HTML` é o `rowspan`.

> **[HTML  rowspan Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp)**
>
> **Original:** The rowspan attribute specifies the number of rows a cell should span.
>
> **Tradução livre:** O atributo rowspan especifica o número de linhas que uma célula deve ocupar.

Considerando o seguinte `JSON`:

```
[
  {
    lab: 'Lab1',
    slogan: 'slogan 1',
    analista: 'Analista 1',
    documento: 'Documento 1'
  },
  {
    lab: 'Lab1',
    slogan: 'slogan 1',
    analista: 'Analista 2',
    documento: 'Documento 2'
  },
  {
    lab: 'Lab1',
    slogan: 'slogan 1',
    analista: 'Analista 3',
    documento: 'Documento 3'
  },
  {
    lab: 'Lab2',
    slogan: 'slogan 2',
    analista: 'Analista 4',
    documento: 'Documento 4'
  }
]
```

Criei uma função `organizar` que transforma-o em:

```
[
  {
    lab: 'Lab1',
    slogan: 'slogan 1',
    documentos: [{
      analista: 'Analista 1',
      documento: 'Documento 1'
    }, {
      analista: 'Analista 2',
      documento: 'Documento 2'
    }, {
      analista: 'Analista 3',
      documento: 'Documento 3'
    }]
  },
  {
    lab: 'Lab2',
    slogan: 'slogan 2',
    documentos: [{
      analista: 'Analista 4',
      documento: 'Documento 4'
    }]
  }
]
```

Sendo assim apliquei o `rowspan` e percorri o elemento que foi formado (`documentos`) para criar as outras linhas. Note que criei um `ng-repeat` adicional que ignora o registro de índice 0 para que as demais linhas sejam mostradas. Exemplo funcionando a seguir:

```js
angular
  .module('meuModulo', []);

angular
  .module('meuModulo')
  .controller('MeuController', MeuController);

MeuController.$inject = [];

function MeuController() {
  var vm = this;

  iniciar();

  function iniciar() {
    var base = [{
        lab: 'Lab1',
        slogan: 'slogan 1',
        analista: 'Analista 1',
        documento: 'Documento 1'
      },
      {
        lab: 'Lab1',
        slogan: 'slogan 1',
        analista: 'Analista 2',
        documento: 'Documento 2'
      },
      {
        lab: 'Lab1',
        slogan: 'slogan 1',
        analista: 'Analista 3',
        documento: 'Documento 3'
      },
      {
        lab: 'Lab2',
        slogan: 'slogan 2',
        analista: 'Analista 4',
        documento: 'Documento 4'
      }
    ];
    ordenar(base);
  }

  function ordenar(base) {
    var organizados = {};
    vm.dados = [];

    angular.forEach(base, function percorrer(item) {
      if (angular.isUndefined(organizados[item.lab])) {
        organizados[item.lab] = {};
        organizados[item.lab].lab = item.lab;
        organizados[item.lab].slogan = item.slogan;
        organizados[item.lab].documentos = [];
      }

      organizados[item.lab].documentos.push({
        analista: item.analista,
        documento: item.documento
      });
    });

    for (var lab in organizados) {
      vm.dados.push(organizados[lab]);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="meuModulo">
  <div ng-controller="MeuController as vm">
    <table>
      <tbody ng-repeat='dado in vm.dados'>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="{{dado.documentos.length}}">{{dado.lab}}</td>
          <td rowspan="{{dado.documentos.length}}">{{dado.slogan}}</td>
          <td>{{dado.documentos[0].analista}}</td>
          <td>{{dado.documentos[0].documento}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat='documento in dado.documentos' ng-if="$index > 0">
          <td>{{documento.analista}}</td>
          <td>{{documento.documento}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Resposta para uma pergunta similar no [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/): [Use of rowspan to group hierarchical data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104750/use-of-rowspan-to-group-hierarchical-data#26834906)